# Need assistance with pexpect module - script doesn't find the match

Tags: python, pexpect

I'm writing a small piece of code to telnet into a switch and give username and password. I use pexpect spawn class for achieving this.

i have created a prompt_list with looking out for 'login' and 'password' and then enter username and password.

the problem that i see is pexpect matches 'login' but not the password. after running it for 2 -3 times, then it matches. do i have to add some delay or something like that to make it work on the first time.

can someone kindly help...

```
try:
    child = pexpect.spawn(cmd, timeout= 100)
    child.logfile = sys.stdout
    child.sendline('\n')
    conn = True
except:
    print ' some exception occured'                
if conn:
    i = child.expect(prompt_list, timeout = 10)
    if i == 0:
        print 'inside login prompt'
        child.sendline('admin')
        i = child.expect(prompt_list, timeout = 10)
    if i == 1:
        print 'Inside password prompt'
        child.sendline('password')
        i = child.expect(prompt_list, timeout = 10)
```

my prompt_list is:

```
prompt_list = ['login:','Password:']
```

when i run this, i get the following error

```
Switch login: inside login prompt
admin
```

the prompt that i get when i login to switch manually is as follows.

```
switch login: admin
Password:
```

Comment: there are much simpler ways to do what you want http://pastebin.com/GYzgP0A8

Comment: Take a look at [telnetlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham OP may prefer to use pexpect for the commands he plans to issue later.

Comment: Is the script running on linux? Some telnet servers want Windows style newlilnes. Try replacing `child.sendline('admin')` with `child.send('admin\r\n')`.

Comment: @tdelaney, it is the child.sendline('\n') that is causing the issue,  adding "\n" with sendline will also cause more problems.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - good call.. I didn't notice that first sendline at the top of the script. However, I've had similar problems that were solved w/ `send('...\r\n')` (not `sendline`).

Comment: @tdelaney, yep, I did not either, only noticed when the output did not line up. Using send you would have to add at least a `\n` but sendline adds it as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `child.sendline('\n')` in the `try/except` is causing a problem:

```
import pexpect
conn = False
import sys

try:
    child = pexpect.spawn("telnet 127.0.0.1", timeout= 100)
    child.logfile = sys.stdout
    conn = True
except:
    print ' some exception occured'

if conn:
    child.expect(":", timeout = 10)
    child.sendline('user')
    child.expect(":", timeout = 10)
    child.sendline('password')
    child.expect(">")
```

Comment: Thanks Padraic.. That helps.. when i removed sendline it works fine. Also, i see that user is prompted twice? i tired setting child.setecho(False) but that didn't help either. any suggestion on this pls?

Comment: No worries, do you mean the login name is echoed twice?

Comment: Yes What ever i give in sendline() except the password, it is repeated twice. The output is as follows:                           switch login: admin
admin
Password: password                                                  
Looks like it is echo'ed but setecho(False) doesn't help

Comment: I don't think setecho seems to work, there are a few posts with similar problems. You could try to disable echo.

Comment: Using Logfile_read serves the purpose.. Refered this site http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.python/pexpect-echoes-twice-for-each-read/1676400

Comment: You should probably use getpass also to get the password.

Comment: I'm a newbie to programming / python .. would you have an example on the usage? meanwhile i will go thro the python docs for its usage.

Comment: `password = getpass.getpass("Enter Password")`

Comment: This will make user-interactive isn't? I was thinking wherein we pass the password through script but stdout doesn't show the password ..

Comment: Yes, If you store the password in plaintext in the script it can be accessed pretty easy or will be echoed to the screen taking normal input